# Twig variable variable

Tags: twig

There are some Twig arrays:

- `feeds`, where a feed gets `category_name`;
- `events`, `news`, `announces` with posts.

Therefore, I can get posts for a category that way:

```
{% for feed in feeds %}
  {% if feed.category_name == "events" %}
  {% for post in events %}
    {{post.title}}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Can I get the same output (as above one loop returns) with `category_name` string set as array name?

Here `feed.category_name` returns `events`:

```
{% for feed in feeds %}
  {% for post in feed.category_name %} {# feed.category_name == "events" #}
    {{post.title}}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You wanna put the category name in array ?

Comment: @JCSama I want to loop the array that has the same name as `category_name`.

Comment: can you post, the `post` variable content

Comment: @JCSama this is [TimberPost](https://github.com/jarednova/timber/wiki/TimberPost) element, [properties](https://github.com/jarednova/timber/wiki/TimberPost#properties).

Comment: I'm not sure I get it, you have have a string `category_name` and you wanna loop on it !!

Comment: @JCSama I have arrays: `events` and `news`. And I have the category with name `events`. So i want to loop on `events` array if `feed.category_name` is  `events` and on `news` array if `feed.category_name` is `news`.

Answer (score 2):

I think what the question author means is – access the array using a name derived from another variable. So that extra conditions are not necessary (and most answers here do propose extra conditions).

Based on my several-minute-research, Volt alone won't let you do it. However, since you can embed PHP code in Volt templates and twig files are compiled to PHP later on anyway, you could do something like:

```
{% for feed in feeds %}
  <?php foreach (${$feed.category_name} as $post) { ?>
    {{post.title}}
  <?php } ?>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I have already tested this – it does work. You may want to add an extra check if the array exists, to avoid warnings:

```
{% for feed in feeds %}
  <?php 
    if (!empty(${$feed.category_name})) { 
      foreach (${$feed.category_name} as $post) { 
  ?>
          {{post.title}}
  <?php } } ?>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you don't like the idea of embedding PHP in your template – don't forget that your template is going to be compiled as PHP anyway!

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Unfortunately, in my environment (WordPress Timber plugin) I can't use PHP in Twig templates.

Comment: Then, I guess, you won't be able to do it the perfect way :-( You will have to manually parse every category name, like others proposed

Answer (score 1):

The global variable `_context` holds all variables in the current context, so you can do this:

```
{% for feed in feeds %}
    {% for post in _context[feed.category_name]|default(null) %}
        {{ post.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The `|default(null)` is required to prevent Twig from throwing an exception if the variable is not found.

[See TwigFiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/qu6peu)

Answer (score 0):

You want the conditional to be "added" to the loop? I think you mean this in [Twig Documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition):

```
<ul>
    {% for user in users if user.active %}
        <li>{{ user.username|e }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**Edit**
Your main issue was with the "variable variable". You can solve this with [the attribute()](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) function and combining the different feeds into one assoc array (categories?).

So perhaps something like (untested):

```
{% for feed in feeds %}
  {% for post in attribute(categories, feed.category_name) %}
    {{post.title}}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I combined `events` and `news` arrays into new one (`all_posts`) and with `{% for post in all_posts if post.has_term( feed.category_name ) %}[[post.title]]{% endfor %}` I can now get posts of the category.

Comment: This workaround has helped with my issue. However, it is not exactly related to *variable variable* topic.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment :

```
{% set new_array = news|merge(events) %}
{% for feed in feeds if attribute(feed.category_name, ['events', 'news']) %}
     {% for post in new_array %}
         {{post.title}}
     {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```